# What is the relationship between sigma algebras, sets and intervals?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

In one of my textbooks it was stated that it was easier to prove that if two random variables X and Y probabilities agreed on all sets, then they agreed on all intervals, than it was to prove that if X and Y probabilities agreed on all intervals, then they agreed on all sets.

**The quote was ripped form Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger on page 33 section 1.6.**

I thought an interval was a set, no? How do sigma algebras, sets and intervals relate to each other?

Comment: It is *much* easier to verify things on intervals than any arbitrary measurable set, especially when measure theory contains such weird and pathological possibilities. So the point of the theorem is to make our lives easier and bypass having to check crazy stuff that we don't want to work with.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis I haven't taken measure theory (plan to though). What is the relationship between an interval and a measurable set?

Comment: As mentioned in JacobsonRadical's answer, the main sigma algebra we are interested is the Borel sigma algebra generated by countable set operations $\cup, \cap, ^c$ of the intervals. 

But the point that should be hammered home is that this is very lax and all many unintuitive sets are allowed by this (which is good! we want measure theory to work with as much things as possible). But when it comes to verifying things, it is not so nice having to check properties for a set you can barely imagine. What is easier, checking the preimage $X^{-1}(B)$ of a fractal like the cantor set, or $(a,b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given my understanding of your post, you are asking the following question:

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be our probability space and let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with state space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is the real line and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma-$algebra.
>
> Denoted by $\mathfrak{I}$ the collection of all intervals on $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Then, show that if $\mathbb{P}(X\in I)=\mathbb{P}(Y\in I)$ for all $I\in\mathfrak{I}$, then $\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\mathbb{P}(Y\in A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

The proof is immediate.

Note that all the sets in the Borel $\sigma-$algebra (also called Borel sets) on $\mathbb{R}$ are generated by open, closed and half open half closed intervals (union of them, complement of each of them or the union of them, intersection of them, etc.)

But you know that $\mathbb{P}(X\in I)=\mathbb{P}(Y\in I)$ for all intervals $I$, then they must agree on any $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, since you can decompose $A$ into several intervals, so that you decompose the probability into several probabilities.

For instance, if $A=(a,b]\cup [c,d)$, for $c>b$ (so that the intervals are disjoint), then 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X\in A)= \mathbb{P}(X\in (a,b]\cup [c,d))&=\mathbb{P}(X\in (a,b])+\mathbb{P}(X\in [c,d))\\
&=\mathbb{P}(Y\in (a,b])+\mathbb{P}(Y\in [c,d))\\
&=\mathbb{P}(Y\in (a,b]\cup [c,d))\\
&=\mathbb{P}(Y\in A).
\end{align*}
where the second line is due to the hypothesis that $\mathbb{P}(X\in I)=\mathbb{P}(Y\in I)$ for all intervals $I$.

Even though you have overlapping intervals, you will still be fine, since for instance you have $A=(a,b]\cup [c,d)$ for $a<c<b$, then 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X\in A)= \mathbb{P}(X\in (a,b]\cup [c,d))&=\mathbb{P}(X\in (a,b])+\mathbb{P}(X\in [c,d))-\mathbb{P}(X\in [c,b])\\
&=\mathbb{P}(Y\in (a,b])+\mathbb{P}(Y\in [c,d))-\mathbb{P}(Y\in [c,b])\\
&=\mathbb{P}(Y\in (a,b]\cup [c,d))\\
&=\mathbb{P}(Y\in A).
\end{align*}

You could try different examples to convince yourself (try complement, intersection, intersection of complements, complements of union, etc.)

---

You actually point out a good idea which is still commonly used even though you move further and upper in the probability theory:

> If you can prove a statement is true on every generating sets of a collection, then the statement is true on everything in that collection.

The idea is simple but when you move higher the argument become tricker and harder.

I will point you to **Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ Theorem** which is extremely useful for such kind of argument.